# Mongoid 3 bulk updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Bulk updates are no longer working after upgrading to Mongoid 3. In Mongoid 2, I had the following:

```
Shift.where(
  :account_id => current_account.id,
  :location => self.department.location.name,
  :department => self.department.name,
  :position => self.name_was,
  :color => self.color_was,
  :date.gte => Date.current
).update_all(position: self.name, color: self.color)
```

I know the criteria is returning results but it no longer updates the documents. Here's the statement in Mongoid 3:

```
Shift.where(
  :account_id => current_account.id,
  :location => self.department.location.name,
  :department => self.department.name,
  :position => self.name_was,
  :color => self.color_was,
  :date.gte => Date.current
).update(position: self.name, color: self.color)
```

I'm running Rails 3.2.7 and Mongoid 3.0.3. Has anything changed that I'm not aware of? Also here's the entry from the logs:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=development collection=shifts selector={"$query"=>{"account_id"=>"5017e8774f4e481fe3000001", "location"=>"Downtown", "department"=>"Cashes", "position"=>"Cash 1", "date"=>{"$gte"=>2012-08-01 00:00:00 UTC}}, "$orderby"=>{"start_at"=>1}} update={"$set"=>{:position=>"Cash A", :color=>"#42ed23"}} flags=[:multi] (0.2141ms)
```

However, nothing gets updated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your query use a String like account_id, not a Moped::BSON::ObjectId.

If you do the where without the update. You have no result I supposed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know that is not the problem. I've run the where without the update and it does return results.